# .NET Need to convert XML into another format

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-serialization

I am making an MVC application where I am creating an XML from Dataset. Now I need to convert that XML into another format for repeating ID node as below.

Original XML :

```
<Requirements>
  <Requirement>
    <ID>Req97</ID>
    <VagueWord>or</VagueWord>
    <Suggestion>Keep each requirement in a single sentence.</Suggestion>
    <Explanation>Suggests that you are combining requirements. Requirements that contain conjunctions/disjunctions (AND/OR) are dangerous and can lead to downstream problems in defining scope of the requirement.</Explanation>
    <VaguePhrase>Marketing or Servicing</VaguePhrase>
    <ContentText>If a user is identified as Marketing or Servicing, then the Campaign Management (CM) hyperlink should be displayed.</ContentText>
    <VagueTypeText>Not Standard</VagueTypeText>
  </Requirement>
  <Requirement>
    <ID>Req97</ID>
    <VagueWord>should</VagueWord>
    <Suggestion>Use 'shall/must/will' for requirements,</Suggestion>
    <Explanation>Is often ambiguous, or inappropriate. Some readers will interpret these as optional or advisory, others as required.</Explanation>
    <ContentText>If a user is identified as Marketing or Servicing, then the Campaign Management (CM) hyperlink should be displayed.</ContentText>
    <VagueTypeText>Not Standard</VagueTypeText>
  </Requirement>
  <Requirement>
    <ID>Req98</ID>
    <VagueWord>Unless</VagueWord>
    <Suggestion>Specify each conditions explicitly. One condition per requirement.</Suggestion>
    <Explanation>Is an escape clause. Requirements with escape clauses are not testable. The word implies additional condition to the requirement.</Explanation>
    <ContentText>Unless Sleep, Latency, Noise, or apply conditions are present, the data transmissions will contain the code for Normal Operation.</ContentText>
    <VagueTypeText>Not Standard</VagueTypeText>
  </Requirement>
</Requirements>
```

Expected XML :

```
<Requirements>
  <Requirement>
    <ID>Req97</ID>
     <VagueWords>
    <VagueWord id="1">or</VagueWord>
    <VagueWord id="2">should</VagueWord>
    </VagueWords>
    <Suggestions>
    <Suggestion id="1">Keep each requirement in a single sentence.</Suggestion>
    <Suggestion id="2">Use 'shall/must/will' for requirements,</Suggestion>
    </Suggestions>
    <Explanations>
    <Explanation id="1">Suggests that you are combining requirements. Requirements that contain conjunctions/disjunctions (AND/OR) are dangerous and can lead to downstream problems in defining scope of the requirement.</Explanation>
    <Explanation id="2">Is often ambiguous, or inappropriate. Some readers will interpret these as optional or advisory, others as required.</Explanation>
    </Explanations>
    <VaguePhrases>
    <VaguePhrase id="1">Marketing or Servicing</VaguePhrase>
    <ContentText id="1">If a user is identified as Marketing or Servicing, then the Campaign Management (CM) hyperlink should be displayed.</ContentText>
    </VaguePhrases>
    <ContentTexts>
    <ContentText id="2">If a user is identified as Marketing or Servicing, then the Campaign Management (CM) hyperlink should be displayed.</ContentText>
    </ContentTexts>
    <VagueTypeTexts>
    <VagueTypeText id="1">Not Standard</VagueTypeText>
    <VagueTypeText id="2">Not Standard</VagueTypeText>
    </VagueTypeTexts>
  </Requirement>
 <Requirement>
    <ID>Req98</ID>
     <VagueWords>
    <VagueWord>Unless</VagueWord>
     </VagueWords>
     <Suggestions>
    <Suggestion>Specify each conditions explicitly. One condition per requirement.</Suggestion>
    </Suggestions>
    <Explanations>
    <Explanation>Is an escape clause. Requirements with escape clauses are not testable. The word implies additional condition to the requirement.</Explanation>
    </Explanations>
    <ContentTexts>
    <ContentText>Unless Sleep, Latency, Noise, or apply conditions are present, the data transmissions will contain the code for Normal Operation.</ContentText>
    </ContentTexts>
    <VagueTypeTexts>
    <VagueTypeText>Not Standard</VagueTypeText>
    </VagueTypeTexts>
  </Requirement>
</Requirements>
```

I need to add attribute as "id" only for repeating node ID. Also please let me know if this expected XML is not a valid XML format

Comment: Is it possible for you to edit the DataSet to generate the second XML?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis My Question is if we can change this existing XML into that Expected XML programmatically ? We can use serialization also if that can give desired output

Comment: @FelipeDeguchi  I am using this simple code to generate XML from DB
DataSet ds = new DataSet("Requirements");
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
                    adapter.Fill(ds, "Requirement");
                    ds.WriteXml(FileName);

Is it possible to edit this code to generate second XML ouput ?

Comment: In your sql, you have requirements that can have the same ID?

Comment: @FelipeDeguchi : Yes.. it is not Primary key column..

Comment: @AmitBhosale You know that's not normalized, right? A normalized database would have the requirement having a list of vague words. `<Requirements>
  <Requirement>
    <ID>Req97</ID>
    <VagueWords>
        <VagueWord id="1">or</VagueWord>
        <VagueWord id="2">should</VagueWord>
    </VagueWords>
 </Requirement>
 <Requirement>`

Comment: @FelipeDeguchi : Yes initially that was not normalized. I have edited the question with updated XML.